# Is there a way to find a value in a dictionary if the key has multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for example:

```
a = {}


class Person:
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value


oject = Animal("foo", 2)
a[oject.getName()] = oject.getValue(), oject, oject.getName()
valuee = 2
```

How would I look for valuee in the dictionary a? I have looked at other articles but most are unhelpful so I thought to turn to this website. Are there any other details I need to add to this post?

Comment: Perhaps you can just clarify this line `oject = Animal("foo", 2)`.  Should this be `oject = Person("foo", 2)`  instead?

Comment: Dictionaries are made for key → value lookups. If you have to do the opposite you might want to check if you have the right data structure.

Comment: You never put anything in the dictionary or retrieve values from it in this example... Also, a dict can have only one value per key, unless that value is itself a list which you'd have to handle specifically.

Comment: Oh ye, I forgot to change that

Comment: @KlausD. I still don't know what to do with this since I need to create a lot of class objects from a loop and have no clue how to store these objects after each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would be likelier to get helpful answers if you took the trouble to post working code, and if it were clear from the title of your question what you are trying to do. Your title says you want to find a value but your code is assigning a value.

```
class Person:
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class Animal(Person):    #without this your assignment to oject will fail
    pass

oject = Animal("foo", 2)
a = vars(oject)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'foo', 'value': 2}
```

Now this answer may be not what you meant at all. If not, try editing your question to explain whether you are trying to find values in a dictionary or assign them to a dictionary, ensure that the code you present actually works, and say clearly what output you expect.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted thank you so much and I'll keep your criticism in mind for future answers. Thank you a lot!

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it.

Comment: Excuse me, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a classic case of multiple assignment. In Python (based on [this](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/) article), when you do a multiple assignment to a single variable, it becomes a tuple. In this case, assigning multiple variables to a dictionary key is the same principle; it becomes a tuple. To access it's data, use it like any other tuple.

`a["foo"][0]`

To look for `valuee` in `a`, and return the appropriate key, you can iterate over the items in `a`.

```py
for pair in a.items():
    if pair[1][0] == valuee:
        return pair[0]
```

Or, as you also include the object and it's name in the tuple, you can iterate over `a.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

So the code is a bit ambiguous.  Also, in your dictionary assignment you assign some of the Person object attributes as well as the whole object.  This does not seem efficient.  It may be useful to the readers to understand what exactly you whish to accomplish with this code, it may inform better answers.

However, working with your code and assuming `oject = Animal("foo", 2)` should be `oject = Person("foo", 2)`, you can get to `value` like this:

`a["foo"][0]` or `a["foo"][1].getValue()`

Depending on what you want to do with this code it may be better to just have a dictionary `a` of objects eg:  `a[oject.getName()] = oject`.  In this way you can access all attributes and methods via `a["foo"].getName()` etc.